# WSH .Exec and .Execute won't run custom Jscript files

Tags: exec, execute, jscript, wsh

When I try `.Exec()` I get the error "not a valid win32 application".  This is the code that produces it:

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        try {
        var subRoutine = oShell.Exec("sayTest.js")
        } catch (e) {
            WScript.Echo('Error Message: ' + e.message);
            WScript.Echo('Error Description: ' + e.description);
            WScript.Sleep(15000);
        }
```

In the case of `.Execute()` I get the error "Automation server can't create object":

```
var Controller = WScript.CreateObject("WSHController");
        try {
        var RemoteScript = Controller.CreateScript("sayTest.js");
        } catch (e) {
            WScript.Echo('Error Message: ' + e.message)
        }
        try {
        RemoteScript.Execute();
        } catch(e) {
            WScript.Echo('Error Message: ' + e.message)
        }
```

Now I can get `.Run()` to work just fine, but it's not ideal for my purposes because it doesn't offer a `processID` property or `Terminate()` method which are critical for my application.  I've tried using fully qualified paths for both `.Exec` and `.Execute()` but that doesn't work either.  These are the paths I've tried:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MIDIOX\WSH\sayTest.js`

`C:/Program Files (x86)/MIDIOX/WSH/sayTest.js`

`C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MIDIOX\\WSH\\sayTest.js`

Answer (score 2):

.Exec tries to start an executable, not a shell that may know (ftype, assoc) how to use c/wscript.exe to run a .js. So mention c/wscript in your command line; to be on the safe side, use full quoted pathes for both the .exe and the .js.

Evidence:

25880027-A.js:

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var aCmds = [
    "25880027-B.js",
    "cscript 25880027-B.js"
];
for (var xCmd in aCmds) {
    xCmd = aCmds[xCmd];
    WScript.Echo("------ " + xCmd);
    try {
        var subRoutine = oShell.Exec(xCmd);
        WScript.Echo(subRoutine.StdOut.ReadLine());
        WScript.Echo("ok");
    } catch (e) {
        WScript.Echo('Error Message: ' + e.message);
    }
}
```

25880027-B.js:

```
WScript.Echo("25880027-B.js executed.");
```

output:

```
cscript 25880027-A.js
------ 25880027-B.js
Error Message: 25880027-B.js is not a valid Win32 application.

------ cscript 25880027-B.js
25880027-B.js executed.
ok
```